# Crystal Reports breaking groups by data

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have Visual Studio 2015 and I have an existing Crystal Report that has three groups based on technology. It's sorted alphabetically within each technology group. Something like this. (Abbreviated data)

```
Technology 1 = Phone
    IPhone
    Android
Technology 2 = Social Media
    Facebook
    Snapchat
Technology 3 = VOIP
    Skype
```

When the technology changes it prints a new header (without skipping to a new page) then lists the details.

The report works fine, but it needs to be changed. They want Technology 1 and 3
grouped together, followed by Technology 2.

I'm new to Chrystal and there are no experts here to ask and I've googled it for  a day and still haven't solved the issue. Seems an expert would fix this easy.

I've tried to use the designer but the closest I've come to the result I want is I can get it to print ALL three technologies one after the other in the correct order. I.e. 1, 3, 2, but the only time it prints the second header is if the report breaks on a new page, NOT if the technology changes in the middle of the page.

I've been trying to create a formula at the group level that would check to see if the Technology = 1 or 3, print it's header and rows, ELSE Technology = 2, print it's header and rows.

When I try to create a formula I can't see any of the table data, just report elements. I tried to start with something like this:

```
  If {table.Technology = 1}
```

But table doesn't exist in the formula options. It doesn't show up in intellisense.

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233073/group-by-two-fields-in-crystal-reports) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091302/crystal-reports-group-by), but I need the report to break on identifying the group field *value*, not just the fact that the group data changed.

What am I missing? Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: So, the desired result contains only two groups (1U3, 2)? May you describe it? (as you did in the begining of your post for the actual result)

Comment: @heringer: Thanks for the reply. I ended up combining the two on the code behind so the report sees the same ID for the two groups I want combined. Everything I read seemed to indicate that Crystal doesn't have a way around the issue.